AWS Network Load Balancer to Monitor Two Application Load Balancers and Route Traffic to the Active one
I have two ALB's in AWS and would like to have a single NLB above that monitors which one is active and route traffic to just that one. I'm attempting this by creating two target groups with a target type of 'ALB' and adding one ALB to each and then attempting to have the listener forward to both these target groups depending on health check response.
I'm creating these resources via Terraform code and so far have managed to create the NLB but here are my findings:

NLB listeners can only use protocols TCP/UDP/TLS.
Listeners cannot define rules/conditions (Weight/Priority etc.).
Only one default action can be assigned to an NLB listener, so a terraform build attaches just one defined target group.
Target groups of type ALB do not appear to support attaching multiple ALB's.

So, my thoughts/next actions are:

Create a second listener with the second target group as default action - The issue here however, is that the listener cannot use the same TCP port of 80. If I set the second one to 81, would the DNS record pointing to the NLB need to reference the non-standard port?
Use the default single listener to point to a single target group with target type of 'IP' and add both ALB's that way, however, each ALB has one IP address per AZ it spans.

In both scenarios, my thinking is that only one cluster/ALB would be active at any one time and so traffic wouldn't be route to an ALB if it was down, although, you would have a period of time when the second one is built and both are active at the same time.
I'm feeling there should be a better way to do this as feels like I'm trying to gaffer tape a solution together at the moment. Any ideas or pointers?

This is unusual. Can you give more background about the scenario and why you're trying to do this? Suggest you edit your question. There may be a better way to achieve your goal without doing something unusual like this.

In my head this feels reasonable and can't see why an NLB can't simply route traffic to two ALB's with targeted groups configured with weight, however, have since found that I can achieve what I want with weighted/health checking DNS records within Route53. Another solution would be to create a top-level ALB with weighted target groups that point directly to the EKS clusters. This would require a change the the current design we have in place but does provide me with what I was initially looking for.

Regardless of these new realizations, it turns out the solution needs to be more automated and so am now looking at implementing Flagger with Kong API Gateway to do canary deployments to Blue/Green EKS clusters.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/blue-green-or-canary-amazon-eks-clusters-migration-for-stateless-argocd-workloads/

Yes, that's the page I came across to make me realise there's other ways to accomplish what I wanted, however, using Flagger with canary deployments is the desire now and something I'm looking into.

I'm not a K8s expert so I can't comment directly about best practices there, but in general I'd probably look at deploying a new "green" cluster and having a load balancer gradually send more traffic to the new cluster. That has the advantage of testing your deployment automation regularly.
